# How to properly control The Wither in order to break only certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

**I'd like to make a Cobblestone automatic farm that uses The Wither as the breaker, but it seems to me that it could easily get out.**
*What I thought about already (but I don't think it's enough for the whole mecanism): Enclose it in an Obsidian box, put a Glass Block in the wall that connects to another room in which there is a mob, and fill the room with Water, in order to absorb the blasts, but also serve as an ingredient for Cobblestone, and a few Lava.* However, I guess that because of The Withers melee attack, that happens after taking damage (drowning, in this case), it might bust out.
**So, how do I prevent The Wither from breaking the room's walls, and only make it break the Cobblestone that forms?**

Comment: If you have access to creative, you could use repeating command blocks to clone a replica of the room to the location of the actual room every quarter second, making it impossible for the wither to escape.

Comment: No, I don't have acces to Creative Mode on the world where I want to build it (it's on Hardcore Mode). If I had acces to Creative, I wouldn't have needed a Cobblestone farm, right? I could have taken it from the Creative inventory. @ALX

Comment: The wither can break obsidian, so the obsidian cage most definitely isn't enough. You might also want to consider using a TNT-duper, which can be a viable alternative option for free full-auto block breaking.

Comment: One way of solving this could be bringing a Ghast through a Nether portal and going afk near the cobblestone. The Ghast will have to be able to see you, and you would need formidable Blast Protection armor to use it for long

Comment: @FungusKing Cobblestone are Stone can't be blown up by Ghast Fireballs. They're too strong for them.

Comment: Can they break smooth stone? If so, its easy to convert the cobblestone generator into a stone generator,  and the ghast wouldnt be able to get out. Also, if you can, name it with a name tag so it doesn't despawn.

Comment: @FungusKing Stone has the same blast resistance as Cobblestone.

Answer (score 1):

There are tutorials on devices called Wither Cages on the Official Minecraft wiki, incolving several fundamental properties of the Wither's attacks, including:

Head targets
The Main Head and Side Head are the two targets that the Wither attacks. This can be controlled by the use of Snow Golems in a protected area (e.g. in front of the Wither behind enchantment tables, or below the Wither throilugh Iron Bars). The Wither must be able to "see" the targets but not be able to destroy them.

Explosive Properties 
The Wither's movement thriugh the world is often seen to destroy all blocks except bedrock, but immobilising it in blast-resistant blocks (eg Iron Blocks or Obsidian) will often keep it contained,especially if some part of it is covered in water.

I will provide a link to the article at some date, but I am currently busy with other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using end stone. It has a very high blast protection. If you have not gone to the end, try making multiple layers of obsidian and then put something that can hurt the wither, such as lava.

Comment: A source of where you found this information would help.

Comment: I got some other information from this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcwwL9rFVaU . Please skip the video to 6:16 to see that the Ender dragon can not get out of this fake wall. But for the other question, I just know It off the top of my head. Sorry. I hope this will help you.

Comment: End Stone and Obsidian can be broken by Blue Wither Skulls.